# $L_p$ estimate in mixed boundary problem for elliptic equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, duality, regularity

Let $Q$ be convex polygon, $\Gamma$ be a portion of boundary
$\partial Q$ and $H^1_\Gamma(Q)=\lbrace u\in H^1(Q):
u|_\Gamma=0\rbrace$. For $f\in (L_2(Q))^2$ consider the problem
$$
\int_Q A(x)\nabla u \nabla v dx= \int_Q f\cdot\nabla v dx, \,\,
\forall v\in H^1_\Gamma(Q),
$$
here $A$ is symmetric, positively definite matrix with Lipschitz
coefficients.

Can I hope to obtain the estimate
$$\Vert  \nabla u\Vert_{L_p(Q)}\leq C \Vert  f\Vert_{L_p(Q)},$$
(may be under some additional conditions) with $p\in (1,2)$ ? What
are the techniques to obtain this estimate ?

P.S. If one consider Dirichlet problem then the [paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1198129) state the estimate
$$\Vert  \nabla u\Vert_{L_p(Q)}\leq C  \Vert f\Vert_{L_p(Q)}+ \Vert u \rho^{-1}\Vert_{L_p(Q)},$$
with some weight $\rho$ as a "standard" and without proof, but unfortunayely I don't know any reference concerning with estimate.

Comment: What is $\nabla f$ in $L^p(Q)$? This should be the negative Sobolev norm, no? Also, do you want ALL $p \in (1,2)$ or SOME $p \in (1,2)$?

Comment: @Hannes, I'm sorry it was misprint. The estimate  is enough for SOME $p$.

Comment: can you prove something if $ p>2$?   If you can then you can try a duality argument to get the range of $p$ you want... i think...

Comment: @Math604 [K.Groeger](https://eudml.org/doc/164533) proved $W^{1,p}$ estimate for $p>2$ (with some restrictions on $p$). Does duality argument imply isomorphism of operator $A: W^{-1,p}_{\Gamma}\to W^{1,p}_{\Gamma}$?

Comment: i have no clue with the weird boundary conditions (and since $A(x)$ is lipshitz i am sure you can compare something to constant co-efficient case).  But by duality i mean consier Dirichlet case and      $div( A(x) \nabla v(x))= div( g(x)) $  where maybe $g \in L^q$ and maybe you get $W^{1,q}$ estimates on $v$ (here $ q>2$ conjugate of $p$).     Then you get $ \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot g = \int f \cdot \nabla v$.   Peform Holder on the right and then sup over $g$...does this not give something like what you want?

Comment: @Math604, thanks! I hope that even the continuity of coefficients is enough if domain Q is not too "weird"...